# How to label images with no object of interest for an object dection project?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, annotation

I have an object detection project of two classes (person, animal), and I want to use darknet/yolov4 for it. The images can contain person(s) and/or animal(s), or none of these classes. For example, an image may just contain cars and I don't need to detect these cars.

My question is how do I handle the annotation file for this image that contains no object of interest? Do I create an annotation file for it and its content is empty?